# Add TraceId and SpanId in OTEL logs

Tags: spring, spring-boot, open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

I am using OpenTelemtry to monitoring and observe a few Spring boot applications using the default starter provided. I have everything setup and running nicely and I am currently in the process of setting up Log to Metric (and vice-versa) correlation in my visualization backend (Loki/Tempo).

My problem is that I cannot find a way of adding additional fields containing the `trace_id` and `span_id` values in the produced logs in order to setup the correlation.

For reference I am using the latest versions of the spring boot starter. Any ideas as to how this can be achieved?